# Splitting text file and adding line count in header with awk in OSX

Tags: macos, awk

I want to do the following with my text file that contains thousands of lines

- Split the file at the lines starting with `B` (but does not include this line).
- Include the number of lines present in each split file as the header + additional text (i.e. `<number of lines> " 120"`)
- Remove a symbol that starts each line (i.e. `>`)

I have tried the following code that allows me to split the file up, but the number of lines present in the file (as in `NR-1 " 120"`) is cumulative and it is printed at the very end of the split file instead of at the start.

`awk '/^B/{n++; print NR-1 " 120" > filename;close(filename);next}{filename = "part" n ".txt"; print >filename}'`

In my attempts to print it as a header, I have used the following code. But the supposed header does not appear at all.
`awk 'BEGIN{print NR-1 " 120" > filename}; /^B/{n++;close(filename);next};{filename = "part" n ".txt"; print >filename}' inputfile.txt`

and the following  error comes with the above code:
`awk: null file name in print or getline
 source line number 1`

My text file looks something like:

```
>L1212 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L1222 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L1232 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
B       *        -                     |1|
>L4212 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4312 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4412 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4512 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
B       *        -                     |2|
>L4212 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4312 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4412 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4512 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4312 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4412 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>L4512 ATCTATCTTCTATCTGTTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
B       *        -                     |3|
```

Update:
A roundabout to using the script by @mklement0 without using Mawk or GNU awk, I used grep in textwrangler to change all lines starting with `B` to a single character `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Awk or Mawk:

```
awk -v RS='\nB       \\*        -                     \\|[0-9]+\\|\n' 'NF {
  numLines = gsub("(^|\n)>", "\n") # replace line-initial ">" and count lines in block
  fname = "part" ++n               # determine next output filename
  printf "%s%s\n", numLines " 120", $0 > fname # output header + block
  close(fname)                               # close output file
}' file
```

<sup>Note: Unless the last line in the input file is a separator line, the last output file will have a trailing empty line (the data-line count in the header will be correct, however) - the OP has confirmed this not to be a problem.</sup>

- GNU Awk or Mawk are needed, because only they support multi-character regex-based `RS` (input-record separator) values - unlike the BSD `awk` that macOS comes with. It *is* possible to solve this problem differently, but it would be a little more cumbersome.

  - Both GNU Awk and Mawk can be installed on macOS via package manager [Homebrew](http://brew.sh); with Homebrew installed, simply run `brew install gawk` or `brew install mawk`.
- The approach breaks the input into *blocks* of lines, by the `B` separator lines. Thus, each such block must fit into memory as a whole (presumably two copies at once, due to performing a string substitution.
- Having the whole block of lines in memory *before* writing them to the output file is what allows counting the lines up front and adding that information to the *header*.

  - `numLines = gsub("(^|\n)>", "\n")` performs both the removal of the line-initial `>` chars. and determines the number of lines in the block, taking advantage of the fact that `gsub()` returns the number of replacements made.

Comment: This works! Though could you explain the code a little further as to what each line does? As line that starts with B actually contains some filler text along the rest of the line, would there be another input that can remove the contents of that line? eg. `B        -             -                                                                                                                                            |1|`, the ending number is in running order so a blanket code will not be useful here.

Comment: As long as it can be setup on a macOS, its an option.

Comment: Thanks for the script and alert! That shouldn't be a problem as the software ignores empty lines. I've worked around the single character issue without using GNU Awk or Mawk using grep in TextWrangler for now.